# JConsole remote connection james server

Tags: jconsole

I am trying to to get jconsole to connect to james jmx remotely. I set in the remote configuration these parameters:

```
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false
-Djava.rmi.server.hostname=<host ip>
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=<port>
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote
```

And I even set up the parameters to my JAVA_OPTS in local. Anyway, it is not able to connect.

Comment: What is the issue you are having? Are you sure ports are not blocked?

Comment: I have already solved it. I have posted an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error was quite frutating. Where the jmx properties are defined (`jmx.properties file`), there are two parameters:

```
jmx.address=${jmx.address}
jmx.port=${jmx.port}
```

The value `${jmx.address}` was a host name, but it must be a IP address, otherwise it does not connect. It took me some time to realize, I hope this helps.